# storing nagios configuration data in oneCMDB

Tags: network-monitoring, configuration-management, nagios

I want to store my [nagios](http://nagios.org/) configuration data into [oneCMDB](http://www.onecmdb.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page)(configuration management database). What i trying to achieve is i will be developing a GUI app in which one can edit the configurations and that configurations will be stored into the database rather than the plain text files. I read it's developer and administrator documentation but there is not tutorial available for it.

If anyone can give a link to such tutorial then it will be a great help to me since there is no such tutorial available.Any suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I know and understand the term cmdb, there is no real database engine, but instead systems like puppet, chef, or cfengine2 are cmdb's. Like wikipedia explains cmdb: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_management_database

So, you could program add-ons for these systems that would support your nagios config?